# How to get the current page's title in jsf

Tags: jsf, facelets, title, managed-bean

I am able to get the current page's url in jsf from back-end bean using HttpServletRequest. But is there a way to get the current page's title also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not directly possible. It only appears in flavor of a HTML `<title>` tag in the HTTP response associated with the HTTP request. You could theoretically parse the view file using a XML parser and extract the `<title>` element from it, but that's plain clumsy.

Better do it the other way round. Variables which are of interest for the controller belongs in the model anyway, not (hardcoded) in the view. Make title a property of the model and display it in EL like so:

```
<title>#{page.title}</title>
```

You could have a mapping of pages based on their URL, or better, their JSF view ID which has the syntax `/path/filename.xhtml`. If you hold them in a `Map<String, Page>`, then you should be able to get the page's title as follows

```
String title = pages.get(facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId()).getTitle();
```

Comment: Woow thanks a lot. That is exactly what I wanted. I think the 3rd solution would work better for my situation as I am developing a breadcrumb I cannot read from model every time.